# Error thrown with truth values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a dataframe within a function to alter that dataframe. 
I get thrown this error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
def hello(column):
    if data['State'] == 'CA': 
        answer = column * 3 
    return answer
```

This is the outter thing I'm trying to do:

```
data['sup'] = data['Amount paid'].apply(hello, axis=1)
```

'State' is a series of states like CA, VA, NY etc.
'Amount paid' is a number.

I'm trying to make it so that if the State is CA, multiply that row's 'Amount paid' by 3.

Comment: Aside from the error message, what does your function return when `data['State']!='CA'`? And what is the `answer`?

Comment: try looking at data.state == 'CA' - it is a time series,  you need to decide on what to do next with it. please also provide a full and runnable example of you error, replicable at remote computer

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak Why do you think it's a _time_ series? A Series - yes. A time series - probably not.

Comment: @DyZ: right you are, a Series instance

Comment: and probably a cross section )

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 1):

`data['State']` is a Series. Therefore, `data['State'] == 'CA'` is also a Series of boolean values. Do you want all of them to be true for the condition to be true? Or just some of them? In the former case, use `if (data['State'] == 'CA').all():`. In the latter case, `if (data['State'] == 'CA').any():`

Comment: edited my question